# 2 player dice game, where even total gains points and odd total loses points NEA task computer science

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, homework, dice

This is a game for two users who roll 2 dice 5 times. If the total of dice is even the player gains 10 points if it is odd, they lose 5.

If there it is a draw after five rounds then the both users will have to roll one die to determine the winner.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import time
import sys
import random
import operator

total_score2 = 0
total_score1 = 0
rounds = 0
playerOnePoints = 0
playerTwoPoints = 0
print("*****************Welcome To The DICE Game*******************")
print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user and enter 's' to display scores")
ens=input("")
while ens != ("e") and ens != ("n") and ens != ("s"): # if anything else but these characters are entered it will loop until it is correct
    print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user and enter 's' to display scores")
    ens = input()
if ens == "s":
    s = open("scores.txt","r")

    file_content = s.read().splitlines()

    users_points = {i.split()[0]: int(i.split()[2]) for i in file_content}
    best_player = max(users_points.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    print("LeaderBoard: ")
    print("\n")
    print('player with maximum points is {}, this player has {} points'.format(best_player, users_points[best_player]))
    best_players = sorted(users_points, key=users_points.get, reverse=True)
    for bp in best_players:
        print('{} has {} points'.format(bp, users_points[bp])) # This prints all players scores

if ens == "n":
    username=input("Please enter appropiate username: ")
    password1=input("Please enter password: ")
    password2=input("Please re-enter password: ")
    if password1 == password2: # checking if both passwords entered are the same
        print("your account has been successfully been made Thankyou")
        file = open("accountfile.txt","a")
        file.write("username: ")
        file.write(username)
        file.write(" ")
        file.write("password: ")
        file.write(password2)
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
        print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user")
        ens=input(" ")
    if password1 != password2: # if passwords entered are not the same will loop until they are correctly entered
        correctPassword=(password1)
        while True:
            password=input('Enter password again ')
            if password == correctPassword:
                print('Correct password has been entered')
                f = open ("accountfile.txt","a+")
                f.write("username: ")
                f.write(username)
                f.write(" ")
                f.write("password: ")
                f.write(correctPassword)
                f.write("\n")
                f.close()
                print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user")
                en=input(" ")
            print('Incorrect password ')

if ens == "e":
    counter = 0
    check_failed = True
    while check_failed:
        print("Could player 1 enter their username and password")
        username1=input("Please enter your username ")
        password=input("Please enter your password ")
        with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
            for line in username_finder:
                if ("username: " + username1 + " password: " + password) == line.strip():  
                    print("you are logged in")
                    check_failed = False
                    counter = 0
                    check_failed = True
                    while check_failed:
                        print("Could player 2 enter their username and password")
                        username2=input("Please enter your username ")
                        password=input("Please enter your password ")
                        with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
                            for line in username_finder:
                                if ("username: " + username2 + " password: " + password) == line.strip():
                                    print("you are logged in")
                                    check_failed = False
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    print("Welcome to the dice game")
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    while rounds < 5:
                                        total_score2 = total_score2 + playerTwoPoints
                                        total_score1 = total_score1 + playerOnePoints
                                        rounds = rounds + 1
                                        number = random.randint(1,6)
                                        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
                                        playerOnePoints = number + number2
                                        print("Round",rounds)
                                        print("-------------------------------------------")
                                        print("Player 1's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userOneInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userOneInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("Player 1's first roll is", number)
                                        print("Player 1's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userOneInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userOneInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("player 1's second roll is", number2)
                                        if playerOnePoints <= 0:
                                                playerOnePoints = 0
                                        if playerOnePoints % 2 == 0:
                                            playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints + 10
                                            print("Player 1's total is even so + 10 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 1 has",playerOnePoints, "points")
                                        else:
                                            playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints - 5
                                            print("player 1's total is odd so -5 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 1 has",playerOnePoints, "points")
                                            if playerOnePoints <= 0:
                                                playerOnePoints = 0
                                        number = random.randint(1,6)
                                        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
                                        playerTwoPoints = number + number2
                                        print("-------------------------------------------")
                                        print("Player 2's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userTwoInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("Player 2's first roll is", number)
                                        print("Player 2's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userTwoInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("player 2's second roll is", number2)
                                        if playerTwoPoints <= 0:
                                                playerTwoPoints = 0
                                        if playerTwoPoints % 2 == 0:
                                            playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints + 10
                                            print("Player 2's total is even so + 10 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 2 has",playerTwoPoints, "points")
                                        else:
                                            playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints - 5
                                            print("player 2's total is odd so -5 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 2 has",playerTwoPoints, "points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")

                                    print("Total score for player 1 is", total_score1)
                                    print("-------------------------------------------")
                                    print("Total score for player 2 is", total_score2)
                                    print("-------------------------------------------")

                                    if total_score1 > total_score2:
                                        print("Player 1 Wins!")
                                        file = open("scores.txt","a")
                                        file.write(username1)
                                        file.write(" has ")
                                        file.write(str(total_score1))
                                        file.write(" points")
                                        file.write("\n")
                                        file.close()
                                        sys.exit()
                                    if total_score2 > total_score1:
                                        print("Player 2 Wins!")
                                        file = open("scores.txt","a")
                                        file.write(username2)
                                        file.write(" has ")
                                        file.write(str(total_score2))
                                        file.write(" points")
                                        file.write("\n")
                                        file.close()
                                        sys.exit()
                                    if total_score1 == total_score2:
                                        print("Its a draw!")
                                        print("So both players will have to roll one more dice")
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                        print("-------------------------------------------")
                                        print("Player 1's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userOneInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userOneInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("Player 1's first roll is", number)
                                        print("Player 1's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userOneInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userOneInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("player 1's second roll is", number2)
                                        if playerOnePoints % 2 == 0:
                                            playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints + 10
                                            print("Player 1's total is even so + 10 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 1 has",playerOnePoints, "points")
                                        else:
                                            playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints - 5
                                            print("player 1's total is odd so -5 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 1 has",playerOnePoints, "points")
                                        number = random.randint(1,6)
                                        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
                                        playerTwoPoints = number + number2
                                        print("-------------------------------------------")
                                        print("Player 2's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userTwoInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("Player 2's first roll is", number)
                                        print("Player 2's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
                                        userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
                                        if userTwoInput == "roll":
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("player 2's second roll is", number2)
                                        if playerTwoPoints % 2 == 0:
                                            playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints + 10
                                            print("Player 2's total is even so + 10 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 2 has",playerTwoPoints, "points")
                                        else:
                                            playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints - 5
                                            print("player 2's total is odd so -5 points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Player 2 has",playerTwoPoints, "points")
                                            print("-------------------------------------------")
                                        if total_score1 > total_score2:
                                            print("Player 1 Wins!")
                                            file = open("scores.txt","a")
                                            file.write(username1)
                                            file.write(" has ")
                                            file.write(str(total_score1))
                                            file.write(" points")
                                            file.write("\n")
                                            file.close()
                                        if total_score2 > total_score1:
                                            print("Player 2 Wins!")
                                            file = open("scores.txt","a")
                                            file.write(username2)
                                            file.write(" has ")
                                            file.write(str(total_score2))
                                            file.write(" points")
                                            file.write("\n")
                                            file.close()
                                            sys.exit()
                            else:
                                print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")
                                counter = counter + 1
                                if counter == 3:
                                    print("----------------------------------------------------")
                                    print("You have been locked out please restart to try again")
                                    sys.exit()

            else:
                print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")
                counter = counter + 1
                if counter == 3:
                    print("----------------------------------------------------")
                    print("You have been locked out please restart to try again")
                    sys.exit()
```

This was a project that i have been doing in computer science which I have now finished if anyone has any suggestions on how I could make it better they will appreciated alot so please suggest how I can improve it. Also It would be very helpful to me if you could rewrite the parts of my code that need improving or are wrong step by step so I can understand it better

Thanks

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question linking back to this one.

Comment: I didn't know that I shouldn't do that sorry

Comment: @Mast so I should post my updated code on a new question

Comment: Yes. Make sure you add a piece of text about what it does, what is improved and a link to your original question (this one).

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to run your UI text through a spell checker. Example - `exsiting`
- Since each player has more than one attribute (`total_score`, `points`, `password`, etc.) each player should be represented by a class, or at least a `namedtuple`.
- You have a `print` followed by a blank `input("")`. Don't do this; just put the content of the print into the prompt argument of the input call.
- `while ens != ("e") and ens != ("n") and ens != ("s")` should be something like `while ens not in ('e', 'n', 's'):`
- Rather than bare `open`/`close` calls, you should use a proper `with` statement.
- Rather than using a half a dozen `write` calls, consider just issuing one `write` call with a multi-line (triple-quoted) string.
- Something like `"username: " + username1 + " password: " + password` is better done with a `format` call.

Other than that, you really need to strengthen your DRY (don't repeat yourself) skills. Writing a handful of functions for repeated code would be a good start.

Comment: Is it possible for you to re write my code so it isn't so long. it would be very helpful if you did it.  :)

Comment: @colkat406 absolutely not. Then you wouldn't learn. Try it yourself and submit a new review.

Comment: could you show me an example of a namedtuple

Comment: could you also show me how to use a function for username and password becasue it is not working for me

Comment: If it isn't working, that's a question for StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 6):

- The requirements for this game are unclear. Code is always produced to implement a set of well defined and understood requirements, even if you are defining these yourself.
- The code is monolithic, break it down into functions, this is [functional decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_decomposition) and one of the first skills a programmer needs to learn, regardless of language or programming paradigm.
- Use `unittests` to [automatically test](http://pythontesting.net/framework/unittest/unittest-introduction/) the functionality of those methods, learning to use `unittest` to engage in Test Driven development will increase your speed of learning at first and make you a far better developer in the long run.
- The code has a very linear flow, programs should provide flexible flows, break it down into three parts, the setup, the game and the results, wrap these with a menu, to setup, play, see score or exit.  Once each part is complete return to the menu loop.
- What is the point of requiring usernames then referring to Players 1 & 2.
- It include lots of pointless functionality such usernames and password from plain text files, capture the names, but do away with the password, security by obscurity offers no security at all.
- It fails if you enter S when first starting, if the file does not exist use [Exception Handing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) to catch this failure, create the blank file and continue.  Always attempt to recover from error conditions when possible, make this second nature.
- [Always validate user input before proceeding](https://www.101computing.net/number-only/).
- Learn to use the built in language features and libraries, this example plays a similar game with much better usage of Python's built in capabilities.  [How to make this random number game better?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33811/how-to-make-this-random-number-game-better)