# Two-player dice game for NEA task computer science (Updated)

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, homework, dice

This is a game for two users who roll 2 dice 5 times. If the total of dice is even the player gains 10 points; if it is odd, they lose 5.

If there is a draw after five rounds then both users will have to roll one die to determine the winner.

Some updates that I have done to this code include adding functions to it so that it reduces the size of the code, removing repeated code, acting upon the suggestions that were given to me on my old code, and trying to improve my DRY (don't repeat yourself) skills.

I just want suggestions on how I could improve this updated code.

```
import time
import sys
import random
import operator
total_score2 = 0
total_score1 = 0
rounds = 0
playerOnePoints = 0
playerTwoPoints = 0
counter = 0

print("*****************Welcome To The DICE Game*******************")
print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user and enter 's' to display scores")
ens=input("")
while ens not in ('e', 'n', 's'): # if anything else but these characters are entered it will loop until it is correct
    print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user and enter 's' to display scores")
    ens = input()

if ens == "s":
    s = open("scores.txt","r")
    file_content = s.read().splitlines()
    users_points = {i.split()[0]: int(i.split()[2]) for i in file_content}
    best_player = max(users_points.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    print("LeaderBoard: ")
    print("\n")
    print('player with maximum points is {}, this player has {} points'.format(best_player, users_points[best_player]))
    best_players = sorted(users_points, key=users_points.get, reverse=True)
    for bp in best_players:
        print('{} has {} points'.format(bp, users_points[bp])) # This prints all players scores
    print("\n")
    print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user and enter 's' to display scores")
    ens=input("")

if ens == "n":
    file = open("accountfile.txt","r+")
    text = file.read().strip().split()
    check = True
    while check:
        username=input("Please enter appropiate username: ") #Takes input of a username from user
        if username == "": #if no value is entered for the username
            continue
        if username in text: #username in present in the text file
            print("Username is taken please try another one")
        else: #username is absent in the text file
            print("Username has been accepted")
            check = False
            check = True
            while check:
                password1=input("Please enter password: ")
                password2=input("Please re-enter password: ")
                if password1 == password2:
                    if password2 in text:
                        print("Password has been taken please try another one")
                    else:
                        print("Username and Password have sucessfully been made Thankyou")
                        file.write("username: " + username + " " + "password: " + password2 + "\n")
                        file.close()
                        check = False
                else:
                    print("passwords do not match please try again")                         
    file.close()

def write1():
    print("Player 1 ",username1," Wins!")
    file = open("scores.txt","a")
    file.write(username1 + " has " + str(total_score1) + " points" + "\n")
    file.close()
    sys.exit()
def write2():
    print("Player 2 ",username2," Wins!")
    file = open("scores.txt","a")
    file.write(username2 + " has " + str(total_score2) + " points" + "\n")
    file.close()
    sys.exit()
def validation():
    global counter
    print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 3:
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        print("You have been locked out please restart to try again")
        sys.exit()
def game():
    global total_score1
    global total_score2
    global rounds
    global number
    global number2
    global playerOnePoints
    global playerTwoPoints
    total_score2 = total_score2 + playerTwoPoints
    total_score1 = total_score1 + playerOnePoints
    rounds = rounds + 1
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    number2 = random.randint(1,6)
    playerOnePoints = number + number2
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("Round",rounds)
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("Player 1's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    userOneInput = input(">>> ")
    if userOneInput == "roll":
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 1's first roll is", number)
    print("Player 1's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    userOneInput = input(">>> ")
    if userOneInput == "roll":
        time.sleep(1)
        print("player 1's second roll is", number2)
    if playerOnePoints % 2 == 0:
        playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints + 10
        print("Player 1's total is even so + 10 points")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print("Player 1 has",playerOnePoints, "points")
    else:
        playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints - 5
        print("player 1's total is odd so -5 points")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print("Player 1 has",playerOnePoints, "points")
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    number2 = random.randint(1,6)
    playerTwoPoints = number + number2
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("Player 2's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
    if userTwoInput == "roll":
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 2's first roll is", number)
    print("Player 2's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
    if userTwoInput == "roll":
        time.sleep(1)
        print("player 2's second roll is", number2)
    if playerTwoPoints % 2 == 0:
        playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints + 10
        print("Player 2's total is even so + 10 points")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print("Player 2 has",playerTwoPoints, "points")
    else:
        playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints - 5
        print("player 2's total is odd so -5 points")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print("Player 2 has",playerTwoPoints, "points")

if ens == "e":
    counter = 0 
    check_failed = True
    while check_failed:
        print("Could player 1 enter their username and password")
        username1=input("Please enter your username ")
        password=input("Please enter your password ")
        with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
            for line in username_finder:
                if ("username: " + username1 + " password: " + password) == line.strip(): 
                    print("you are logged in")
                    check_failed = False
                    check_failed = True
                    while check_failed:
                        print("Could player 2 enter their username and password")
                        username2=input("Please enter your username ")
                        password=input("Please enter your password ")
                        with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
                            for line in username_finder:
                                if ("username: " + username2 + " password: " + password) == line.strip():
                                    print("you are logged in")
                                    check_failed = False
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    print("Welcome to the dice game")
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    while rounds < 5:
                                        game()
                                    print("-------------------------------------------")
                                    print("Total score for player 1 is", total_score1)
                                    print("-------------------------------------------")
                                    print("Total score for player 2 is", total_score2)
                                    print("-------------------------------------------")
                                    if total_score1 > total_score2:
                                        write1()
                                    if total_score2 > total_score1:
                                        write2()
                                    if total_score1 == total_score2:
                                        print("Its a draw!")
                                        game()
                                        if total_score1 > total_score2:
                                            write1()
                                        if total_score1 < total_score2:
                                            write2()
                            else:
                                validation()

            else:
                validation()
```

[This is the link to my old code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208342/2-player-dice-game-where-even-total-gains-points-and-odd-total-loses-points-nea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make better use of functions to reduce duplication.

Here:

```
def write1():
    print("Player 1 ",username1," Wins!")
    file = open("scores.txt","a")
    file.write(username1 + " has " + str(total_score1) + " points" + "\n")
    file.close()
    sys.exit()

def write2():
    print("Player 2 ",username2," Wins!")
    file = open("scores.txt","a")
    file.write(username2 + " has " + str(total_score2) + " points" + "\n")
    file.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Note how 99% of those functions are identical. The only difference is the usernames and scores. Add those as parameters to the function and pass the data in as arguments. This will make even more sense once you get rid of global variables as the other answer suggested:

```
def write_score(username, score):
    print(username," wins!") # Got rid of the "Player #" part for simplicity
    file = open("scores.txt","a")
    file.write(username + " has " + str(score) + " points" + "\n")
    file.close()

     # This arguably shouldn't be here.
     # Do you really want it to be necessary to close the program after writing?
    sys.exit()
```

Then change the calling code to something like:

```
if total_score1 > total_score2:
    write_score(total_score1, username1)

elif total_score2 > total_score1:
    write_score(total_score2, username2)
```

You don't gain as much with functions if you're just moving two nearly identical chunks of code into two separate, nearly identical functions.

If code looks almost the same, here's a simple way to turn it into a common function: Look at the pieces of code, and determine what is the same, and what is different. Make the different parts parameters of the function and pass that data in, and make the identical parts the body of the function. You can see how I used that with the example above.

This can be made much neater though if you tuck the name and score away into a Player object. That way you aren't needing to deal with those bits of data separately.

---

Everything under `if ens == "e":` should be moved out into its own function. There's no reason to have that much dense code all lumped together. It makes your code much harder to read, and forces you to have a ridiculous amount of nesting/indentation. You should create a function that reads the account information from file, another function that takes that information and checks the supplied login credentials, a function that takes input from the user, and a main procedure function that encompasses the logic of the game.

Splitting it up like that will not only reduces duplication (since then you can, for example, call the "get user input" function twice instead of copying and pasting nearly the same chunk of code), but it will make the program easier to test. To see if loading information works, you just need to feed data to the "load" function and see what it returns back. With how you have it setup now, you need to run the entire program just to see if a small part of it works.

---

Another example of reducing duplication is creating a function to test if a username/password combo is correct. It would make much more sense to write something like:

```
def verify_login(username, password, login_data):
    for line in login_data:
       if ("username: " + username + " password: " + password) == line.strip():
           return True

    return False
```

And then call this function for each player in the main routine.

```
with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
    username1 = input(...)
    password1 = input(...)

    if verify_login(username1, password1, username_finder):
        print("you are logged in")

        username2 = input(...)
        password2 = input(...)

        if verify_login(username2, password2, username_finder):
```

Now, you can test this functionality without ever needing to load data from a file, or even run the program, and you don't need to deal with the whole `check_failed` mess.

That part could be extracted out too so the user is asked to enter a username/password pair until it matches:

```
def ask_for_login(login_data):
    while True:
        username = input(...)
        password = input(...)

        if verify_login(username, password, login_data):
            # Return the verified username that the user entered
            return username

        else:
            validation()
```

Then use it as:

```
with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
    username1 = ask_for_login(username_finder)
    username2 = ask_for_login(username_finder)

    # Once you get rid of the globals, you'd pass "username1" and
    #  "username2" as arguments to "game"
    game()
```

Notice how much nesting this gets rid of.

---

Practice looking at similar looking code and thinking about how it could be made into a function. This entire piece of code could be reduced by probably half once all the duplication is removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help also I have a question, for the user to roll the dice they have to type `roll` and then it displayes what the user rolled but if the user types in anything else but  `roll` it doesn't display what the user rolled. Do you think you could help me?

Comment: Also I can't use the function for verfiying the username/password because in my code it sayes:`username1=input("Please enter your username ")
        password=input("Please enter your password ")` and it is the same thing for player 2 but it is :`username2=input("Please enter username" )` so both usernames are different so how am I suppose to use the function you mentioned above for two different users

Comment: @colkat406 For the second problem, you return the username and password from the function, you don't assign in the function. Dealing with globals makes everything more difficult in the long term. The first change you should make is to do as the other answer suggested and get rid of all the global variables.

Comment: @colkat406 For the first problem, let me wake up a bit more, and I'll look it over.

Comment: @colkat406 Regarding the first question, what you want is good input validation that only accepts defined inputs, and prompts the user for another input when an undefined input is given. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/8117067) is a good primer on the topic.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Im not too sure what you mean in your second answer about the function

Comment: @colkat406 Which part?

Comment: @Carcigenicate The part when you said "you return the username and password from the function, you don't assign in the function"

Comment: @colkat406 I'll elaborate on that when I get home (I'm at work). Basically, you should return data from functions and avoid using globals whenever possible. I'll show you how you can do that when I get home.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok then I hope you can help me asap

Comment: @colkat406 See my edit near the bottom regarding `verify_login` and `ask_for_login`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The format for the account file is this: `username: bob password: b123
username: jason password: j123
` If I enter the first bob's details first then jason's it works but when i do it the other way around it sayes username or password doesn't exists for some reason and I get this problem for the `ask _for_ login part`, could you help me?

Comment: @colkat406 Debugging here isn't really appropriate. I just did up a quick reduced example on the interpreter on my phone though, and it worked. Your save format may have a stray space somewhere, or you accidentally typed an extra space when entering, or you used a capital or something.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I fixed that problem now thanks. I have another question though concerning the dice game, say that the user rolls 1 and 2 which add up to 3 which is an odd number the game will -5 from the 3 which makes the total -2 but I don't want it to go into minus, I want it so that they get 0 points instead of minus points. could you help me?

Comment: @colkat406 This is beyond a code review. If you need help with broken code, you can post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok then I will.

Answer (score 4):

Try to avoid using so many globals. Your code would be better-structured if you made a `Game` class and captured most or all of that state as class member variables.

You made the same spelling mistake here as you did in your previous question. "exsiting" is spelled "existing".

In this code:

```
s = open("scores.txt","r")
```

You open, but fail to close, `s`. Convert this to a `with` statement.

This:

```
users_points = {i.split()[0]: int(i.split()[2]) for i in file_content}
```

relies on this format:

```
file.write(username1 + " has " + str(total_score1) + " points" + "\n")
```

As such, you can convert your `users_points` initialization to:

```
users_points = {}
for line in file_content:
    user, points = re.match('r(\w+) has (\d+) points').groups()
    users_points[user] = int(points)
```

However, that's not ideal. If `scores.txt` doesn't need to be human-readable, then you should store it in a different format - probably JSON. That way, your loading and store can be made much more simple.

Move your global code to a `main` method.

As I recommended in the previous incarnation of this question, and will recommend again, stop issuing blank `input` calls. This:

```
print("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user and 'e' if you are a exsiting user and enter 's' to display scores")
ens=input("")
```

needs to be

```
ens = input("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user, 'e' if you are an existing user, or 's' to display scores: ")
```

Try to convert some of your concatenated strings into f-strings:

```
username1 + " has " + str(total_score1) + " points" + "\n")
```

should become

```
f'{username1} has {total_score1} points\n'
```

This:

```
counter = counter + 1
```

should be

```
counter += 1
```

This:

```
check_failed = False
check_failed = True
```

is quite strange; the first assignment will be overwritten so you should probably just delete it.